# Facebook api server side

Tags: алгоритм, facebook-api

Ребят подскажите, на сайте нужно иметь две авторизации

1. Пользовательская
2. Серверная

Логика какая, сайт в процессе свой работы что-то создает, постит и.т.д. с помощью своей авторизации на своей странице, допустим создаем мероприятия.
А пользователи когда заходят под своей учеткой могут писать комменты и прочие посты в мероприятиях которые созданы сайтом. вот п.2 я представляю как сделать, а п.1. не очень.
Как авторизовать сервер и хранить для него самого свою авторизацию да еще так что бы она не пересекалась с пользовательской?
Сайт на php

Comment: вот эта фраза многого стоит:
> сайт в процессе свой работы что-то создает, постит и.т.д.

если не можете сами написать что вам надо тогда напишите на что это похоже (на какой ресурс).

p.s. судя по всему вам надо просто 2 групы пользователей с разными правами. одна група имеет доступ постить контент (создавать ивенты) другая только каментить (просматривать уже созданные)

Comment: то что создает сайт в процессе работы смысле не имеет для данного вопроса, например мероприятия. можно ограничиться вопросом о том, как сделать что бы сайт самостоятельно в процессе своей работы постил на свою страницу. пользователи тут не причем

Comment: как создавать свои `custom` обьекты и действия:

    http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/


в принцыпе аналогичным образом можно постить все что угодно (т.к. у фейсбука есть уже pre-defined обьекты). тут описано как можно создавать стандартные обьекты:

    http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: это все понятно, не понятно как авторизовать сам сервер, где будет хранится его авторизация, и как сделать что бы она постоянная была, там же токены имеют срок жизни

Comment: почитайте про `opengraph` там есть нужная вам информация, юзеры запрашивают свой токен у фейсбука, приложения поступают аналогично (как именно - см. доки) только для этого им нужно facebook application id + facebook application secret (которые можно посмотреть на dev' странице вашего приложения в FB)